# Shiny R observeEvent with Multiple Conditions from selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinyjs

I'm working on a shiny app and I'm running into difficulty with `observeEvent()` function when creating a complex expression of multiple inputs that all derive from `selectInput()`.

My issue is some of the expressions within the `observeEvent()` function are triggered at startup, causing the event to prematurely execute (i.e. my `actionButton()` is disabled at startup, as it should be, but becomes enabled when at least one of the inputs are selected when ideally I would want it to become enabled only when ALL inputs are selected). As seen below:

```
  observeEvent({
    #input$cohort_file
    input$cohort_IDvar
    input$cohort_index_date
    input$cohort_EOF_date
    input$cohort_EOF_type
    input$cohort_Y_name
    input$cohort_L0
  }, {
    enable("set_cohort_button")
  })
```

For reference, I'm using the `shinyjs` package by @daattali found on github to enable/disable `actionButton()`.

All but the last input (i.e. `input$cohort_L0`) appear to be initialized at startup so `observeEvent()` enables `actionButton` only when `input$cohort_L0` is selected. If you run my app and select input in sequential order from top to bottom, it appears that `observeEvent()` is working as intended. I only discovered that it wasn't working as intended when I decided to choose inputs at random and discovered that selecting `input$cohort_L0` was the only input I needed to select to enable `actionButton()`.

The UI portion of the code looks like this:

```
# Variable selection
                          selectInput('cohort_IDvar', 'ID', choices = ''),
                          selectInput('cohort_index_date', 'Index date', choices = ''),
                          selectInput('cohort_EOF_date', 'End of follow-up date', choices = ''),
                          selectInput('cohort_EOF_type', 'End of follow-up reason', choices = ''),
                          selectInput('cohort_Y_name', 'Outcome', choices = ''),
                          selectInput('cohort_L0', 'Baseline covariate measurements', choices = '', multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE),
```

And I'm using `observe()` to collect the column names of an upload data-set to direct them to `selectInput()` as follows:

```
  ### Collecting column names of dataset and making them selectable input
  observe({
    value <- c("",names(cohort_data()))
    updateSelectInput(session,"cohort_IDvar",choices = value)
    updateSelectInput(session,"cohort_index_date",choices = value)
    updateSelectInput(session,"cohort_EOF_date",choices = value)
    updateSelectInput(session,"cohort_EOF_type",choices = value)
    updateSelectInput(session,"cohort_L0",choices = value)
  })
```

I've looked into using the argument `ignoreInit = TRUE` but it does nothing for my case of having multiple expressions within `observeEvent()`. I've also looked into forcing no default selection in `selectInput()` but had no luck with that.

So my two-part question is how can I execute `observEvent()` when only ALL inputs are selected/how do I stop from the inputs from being initialized at startup?

My entire code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(

  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage("Test",
             tabPanel("Cohort",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          fileInput("cohort_file", "Choose CSV File",
                                    multiple = FALSE,
                                    accept = c("text/csv",
                                               "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                               ".csv")),
                          # Horizontal line ----
                          tags$hr(),
                          # Variable selection
                          selectInput('cohort_IDvar', 'ID', choices = ''),
                          selectInput('cohort_index_date', 'Index date', choices = ''),
                          selectInput('cohort_EOF_date', 'End of follow-up date', choices = ''),
                          selectInput('cohort_EOF_type', 'End of follow-up reason', choices = ''),
                          selectInput('cohort_Y_name', 'Outcome', choices = ''),
                          selectInput('cohort_L0', 'Baseline covariate measurements', choices = '', multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE),
                          # Horizontal line ----
                          tags$hr(),
                          disabled(
                            actionButton("set_cohort_button","Set cohort")
                          )
                          #actionButton("refresh_cohort_button","Refresh")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          DT::dataTableOutput("cohort_table"),
                          tags$div(id = 'cohort_r_template')
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ################################################
  ################# Cohort code
  ################################################

  cohort_data <- reactive({
    inFile_cohort <- input$cohort_file
    if (is.null(inFile_cohort))
      return(NULL)
    df <- read.csv(inFile_cohort$datapath, 
                   sep = ',')
    return(df)
  })

  rv <- reactiveValues(cohort.data = NULL)
  rv <- reactiveValues(cohort.id = NULL)
  rv <- reactiveValues(cohort.index.date = NULL)
  rv <- reactiveValues(cohort.eof.date = NULL)
  rv <- reactiveValues(cohort.eof.type = NULL)

  ### Creating a reactiveValue of the loaded dataset
  observeEvent(input$cohort_file, rv$cohort.data <- cohort_data())

  ### Displaying loaded dataset in UI
  output$cohort_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df <- cohort_data()
    DT::datatable(df,options=list(scrollX=TRUE, scrollCollapse=TRUE))
  })

  ### Collecting column names of dataset and making them selectable input
  observe({
    value <- c("",names(cohort_data()))
    updateSelectInput(session,"cohort_IDvar",choices = value)
    updateSelectInput(session,"cohort_index_date",choices = value)
    updateSelectInput(session,"cohort_EOF_date",choices = value)
    updateSelectInput(session,"cohort_EOF_type",choices = value)
    updateSelectInput(session,"cohort_L0",choices = value)
  })

  ### Creating selectable input for Outcome based on End of Follow-Up unique values
  observeEvent(input$cohort_EOF_type,{
    updateSelectInput(session,"cohort_Y_name",choices = unique(cohort_data()[,input$cohort_EOF_type]))
  })

  ### Series of observeEvents for creating vector reactiveValues of selected column
  observeEvent(input$cohort_IDvar, {
    rv$cohort.id <- cohort_data()[,input$cohort_IDvar]
  })
  observeEvent(input$cohort_index_date, {
    rv$cohort.index.date <- cohort_data()[,input$cohort_index_date]
  })
  observeEvent(input$cohort_EOF_date, {
    rv$cohort.eof.date <- cohort_data()[,input$cohort_EOF_date]
  })
  observeEvent(input$cohort_EOF_type, {
    rv$cohort.eof.type <- cohort_data()[,input$cohort_EOF_type]
  })

  ### ATTENTION: Following eventReactive not needed for example so commenting out
  ### Setting id and eof.type as characters and index.date and eof.date as Dates
  #cohort_data_final <- eventReactive(input$set_cohort_button,{
  #  rv$cohort.data[,input$cohort_IDvar] <- as.character(rv$cohort.id)
  #  rv$cohort.data[,input$cohort_index_date] <- as.Date(rv$cohort.index.date)
  #  rv$cohort.data[,input$cohort_EOF_date] <- as.Date(rv$cohort.eof.date)
  #  rv$cohort.data[,input$cohort_EOF_type] <- as.character(rv$cohort.eof.type)
  #  return(rv$cohort.data)
  #})

  ### Applying desired R function
  #set_cohort <- eventReactive(input$set_cohort_button,{
    #function::setCohort(data.table::as.data.table(cohort_data_final()), input$cohort_IDvar, input$cohort_index_date, input$cohort_EOF_date, input$cohort_EOF_type, input$cohort_Y_name, input$cohort_L0)
  #})

  ### R code template of function
  cohort_code <- eventReactive(input$set_cohort_button,{
    paste0("cohort <- setCohort(data = as.data.table(",input$cohort_file$name,"), IDvar = ",input$cohort_IDvar,", index_date = ",input$cohort_index_date,", EOF_date = ",input$cohort_EOF_date,", EOF_type = ",input$cohort_EOF_type,", Y_name = ",input$cohort_Y_name,", L0 = c(",paste0(input$cohort_L0,collapse=","),"))")
  })

  ### R code template output fo UI
  output$cohort_code <- renderText({
    paste0("cohort <- setCohort(data = as.data.table(",input$cohort_file$name,"), IDvar = ",input$cohort_IDvar,", index_date = ",input$cohort_index_date,", EOF_date = ",input$cohort_EOF_date,", EOF_type = ",input$cohort_EOF_type,", Y_name = ",input$cohort_Y_name,", L0 = c(",paste0(input$cohort_L0,collapse=","),"))")
  })

  ### Disables cohort button when "Set cohort" button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$set_cohort_button, {
    disable("set_cohort_button")
  })

  ### Disables cohort button if different dataset is loaded
  observeEvent(input$cohort_file, {
    disable("set_cohort_button")
  })

  ### This is where I run into trouble
  observeEvent({
    #input$cohort_file
    input$cohort_IDvar
    input$cohort_index_date
    input$cohort_EOF_date
    input$cohort_EOF_type
    input$cohort_Y_name
    input$cohort_L0
  }, {
    enable("set_cohort_button")
  })

  ### Inserts heading and R template code in UI when "Set cohort" button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$set_cohort_button, {
    insertUI(
      selector = '#cohort_r_template',
      ui = tags$div(id = "cohort_insertUI", 
                    h3("R Template Code"),
                    verbatimTextOutput("cohort_code"))
    )
  })

  ### Removes heading and R template code in UI when new file is uploaded or when input is changed
  observeEvent({
    input$cohort_file
    input$cohort_IDvar
    input$cohort_index_date
    input$cohort_EOF_date
    input$cohort_EOF_type
    input$cohort_Y_name
    input$cohort_L0
  }, {
    removeUI(
      selector = '#cohort_insertUI'
    )
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code chunk that you're passing to the observeEvent as the trigger event is

```
{
  input$cohort_IDvar
  input$cohort_index_date
  input$cohort_EOF_date
  input$cohort_EOF_type
  input$cohort_Y_name
  input$cohort_L0
}
```

This means that, just like any other reactive code block, when ANY of these values changes, that reactive block is considered invalidated and therefore the observer will trigger. So the behaviour you're seeing makes sense.

It sounds like what you want is to execute only when all values are set. That sounds like a great use of the `req()` function! Try something like this:

```
observe({
  req(input$cohort_IDvar, input$cohort_index_date, input$cohort_EOF_date, ...)
  enable("set_cohort_button")
})
```

Note that for `shinyjs::enable()` specifically, you can instead use the `shinyjs::toggleState()` function. I think in this case the `req()` function is the better option though.