# R Shiny: eventReactive/ObserveEvent, eventExpr has AND

Tags: r, shiny

How do i make the `eventReactive`/`ObserveEvent`, `eventExpr` expression depend on two inputs, say an `actionButton` and a `selectInput`. I am trying to update the values of a third `selectInput`, only if the first `selectInput` changes and the action button is clicked. But keep the original values if only the `actionButton` is clicked, and do nothing if just the first `selectInput` is changed.

I tried:

```
observeEvent({input$selectInput1 & input$actionButton}, {
    updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "input2", label = "b", choices = input$selectInput1, selected = input$selectInput1)
})
```

But I can't use `&` in the `eventExpr`

Comment: Could you consider a separate `reactiveValues` that will update when a user selects a `selectInput` or `actionButton`? Then have a second `observer` that will check to ensure both have been selected before performing `updateSelectInput` (and then resetting the `reactiveValues`). It's not very elegant, but could work...

Comment: how would I write the observer that ensures both have been selected?

Comment: See the answer I provided - does this have the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer comes from this thread: [Shiny R observeEvent with Multiple Conditions from selectInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55544176/shiny-r-observeevent-with-multiple-conditions-from-selectinput) and I wanted to make it visible here as well, because it worked well for me.

In your case the fix would probably be

```
observeEvent(req(input$selectInput1, input$actionButton), {
    updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "input2", label = "b", choices = input$selectInput1, selected = input$selectInput1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
observeEvent(list(input$selectInput1, input$actionButton), {
    updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "input2", label = "b", choices = input$selectInput1, selected = input$selectInput1)
})
```

Comment: this is effectively an OR not an AND. this will trigger when either the `actionButton` is clicked or the value of `selectInput1` is changed. I want both, the `actionButton` and the `selectInput1` is changed, if just one is changed i dont want the update to happen.

Comment: @Courvoisier Ah ok sorry. I'm not sure this makes sense because the two inputs never change simultaneously.